# XSLT How to access the value of an attribute when it is the target of a match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have found a lot about how to access the value of an attribute when an XSLT match is for an element.  But I can't seem to find a way to access the value of an attribute when the match is for that attribute.

For example here is a piece of my original xml file:

```
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" alttext="">
      <mfrac>
        <mn>20</mn>
        <mn>60</mn>
      </mfrac>
      <mo>=</mo>
      <mfrac>
        <mi mathvariant="bold">x</mi>
        <mn>100</mn>
      </mfrac>
    </math>
```

And here is the template I am using (that doesn't work):

```
  <xsl:template match="mathml:math//mathml:mi/@mathvariant">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".='bold'">
               <xsl:attribute name="mathvariant">
                  <xsl:value-of select="'bold-sans-serif'"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".='italic'">
               <xsl:attribute name="mathvariant">
                  <xsl:value-of select="'sans-serif-italic'"/>
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

I want to use the choose stmt to change the mathvariant attribute of the  element based on it's value. I know I need to match the attribute itself in order to change it's value (that part works), but I don't know how to get access to the matched attribute's value in the when statement. 
                      test=". = 'bold'"       doesn't work.
The "dot" doesn't mean what I think it means if the match is an attribute.
What am I missing?

Comment: Your code is correct. Whatever the bug is, it's not in your `xsl:when/@test` expressions. What symptoms are you observing? Are you sure that the template rule ever gets invoked?

Comment: Yes - if I take out the choose and just add the attribute, it works. But I want to set the attribute value differently depending on it's current value.  It has to be related to the "dot" not being the same thing when you have the handle of a node vs. the handle of an attribute.

Comment: Actually, the problem is the xsl:copy. I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `xsl:copy`. When the context item is an attribute, `xsl:copy` creates a copy of the attribute, and any instructions in the body of the `xsl:copy` instruction are ignored. Try simply removing the `xsl:copy` start and end tags. I don't guarantee that will work, because we haven't seen the code that contains the `xsl:apply-templates` that triggers this template rule, but it should at least ensure that the `xsl:choose` gets executed.

Your use of `test=".='bold'"` is perfectly OK: when the context item is an attribute, `"."` in an atomizing context gives you the string value of the attribute.

Comment: This worked! Thank you for sharing that. I have learned a lot through this process!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the value of the attribute `mathvariant` with another value, you can use the following templates. They both work together with the *indentity template* copying the rest of your XML.

```
<xsl:template match="mathml:mi/@mathvariant[.='bold']">
  <xsl:attribute name="mathvariant">
    <xsl:value-of select="'bold-sans-serif'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="mathml:mi/@mathvariant[.!='bold']">
  <xsl:attribute name="mathvariant">
    <xsl:value-of select="'sans-serif-italic'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

So for XSLT-1.0 use the *identity template*

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
   <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and for XSLT-3.0 you can use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
```

---

If you want to stick with an `xsl:choose`, put it in the `xsl:attribute` and match the related element:

```
<xsl:template match="mathml:mi/@mathvariant">
  <xsl:attribute name="mathvariant">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".='bold'">                 
              <xsl:value-of select="'bold-sans-serif'"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="'sans-serif-italic'"/>                
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I do have that solution working, but thought that one template with a choose stmt would be a better, more understandable solution.  Is there no way to access the value of the current attribute?

Comment: I added an `xsl:choose` solution.

Comment: This is a great solution if I could get it to work. I made the otherwise value set to "sans-serif" which is what I wanted anyway (bonus!). But now when it runs, it doesn't change the bold or italic lines it only changes lines that have no mathvariant attribute to mathvariant="sans-serif". So it seems to recognize the when expressions and doesn't do the otherwise code, but it doesn't do the when code either.

Comment: The code is correct, then there must be another error. I provided two ways of approaching this problem. So the best way in this situation is probably to accept this answer and create a new question from this question's code with a more complete [mcve]. This is to avoid creating a mess (out-of-sync) situation between question and answer.

Comment: Please allow me to respectfully disagree. My original question was about how to change the value of an existing attribute during xslt transformation. The (choose) solution you have provided me here still does not allow me to do that. I understood that the only way to replace an attribute value was to match on the attribute itself and then I needed to access the value of that attribute in order to use the choose statement. Is it possible that I can't create a new mathvariant attribute for bold & italics because there is already one there?

Comment: Sorry. I was mistaken. I changed my answer with two ways of directly matching the attribute. I hope that this answer better suits your needs.

Comment: For some reason the "dot" does not work when the current context is an attribute and not a node.  There must be a way to do this.  How can you be able to match on an attribute but not see the value it has?

Comment: As I above and Michael Kay in the comments above said: your code is correct. I tested every version of my answer and they all worked. So your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Your answer was also correct - it did not have the xsl:copy in it and I did not notice that mine did.  I actually ended up using the answer you previously removed - it worked once I got the xsl:copy lines in the right places. Thank you.